# Getting "undefined method `todo_item'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Anyone can help solve this problem NoMethodError (undefined method `todo_items')?

This is my controller file:

```
 class Api::TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
 skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
 before_filter :find_todo_list

 def create

 item = @list.todo_items.new(item_params)
if item.save
  render status: 200, json: {
    message: "Successfully created To-do Item.",
    todo_list: @list,
    todo_item: item
  }.to_json
else
  render status: 422, json: {
    message: "To-do Item creation failed.",
    errors: item.errors
  }.to_json
end
end

private

def item_params
  params.require("todo_item").permit("content")
end

def find_todo_list
  @list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
end
```

end

This is my TodoList Model code:

```
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

This is my TodoItem Model code:

```
class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

This is error message of the undefined method todo_items:

```
Started POST "/api/todo_lists/5/todo_items/" for ::1 at 2016-05-07     16:57:45 +0800
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
 Processing by Api::TodoItemsController#create as JSON
 Parameters: {"content"=>"new", "todo_list_id"=>"5", "todo_item"=>{"content"=>"new"}}
 TodoList Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "todo_lists".* FROM "todo_lists" WHERE "todo_lists"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

 NoMethodError (undefined method `todo_items' for #    <TodoList:0x007f82e2dbc088>):
 app/controllers/api/todo_items_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please add your model code in your question

Comment: already add the model code, please check.

Comment: Just change TodoList model and add 
"has_many :todo_items" there

Comment: now is the another error :ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'todo_list_id' for TodoItem.):
  app/controllers/api/todo_items_controller.rb:11:in `create'

Comment: add a migration for add todo_list_id in todo_list table

Comment: your code is not in proper structure, first read about association and create table based on that

Comment: already add the todo_list_id to table,
now showing the NameError (uninitialized constant TodoList::TodoItems),
can i know what happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you add **todo_items** in the TodoList model?

has_many :todo_items